# Create Object named by String

Tags: java, string, object, named, createobject

Is it possible to create a method that can create objects named by `String`?

```
private static int a = 0;
public static void CreateNew() {
    Object ("number" + a) = new Object();
    a++;
}
```

If you know, how would I do it?

Comment: What language is this, Java?

Comment: What are you using this for? Is it something that you could just achieve by having a hashmap holding the objects that are have the string as their key?

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to use a java.util.Map / HashMap in this case.

```
Map<String,String> strMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
strMap.put("number" + a, "value_for_this_string");
```

Java is a compiled language and not an interpreted language like the scripting languages where you can do something like this straightforward.